# Apache Spark Streaming : How to compare 2 dataframes in 2 dstreams

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner with Apache Spark. I am trying to run a stream job which recieves some data ,convert it into dataframe and run some processing like joining and removing duplicates etc . Now I have to cache this processed data so that I can append this with next dstream (using some union/join) and do processing again.

I tried using dataframe.cache() to cache and re use this in next stream batch.

For example,if df is rdd formed from dstream.

```
   foreachrdd{
new =df.unionAll(processed)
new.registerTempTable("TableScheme")
sql.( //perform inner join and some other processing)
processed=new
processed.cache();

}
```

When we perform Dataframe.cache or Dataframe.persist() are we caching the actual data or the DAG / transformations applied ? When second stream comes, my program exits with

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[1] at socketTextStream after its blocks have been removed!
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cache()` functionality performs the processing defined in the DAG up to the `cache()` call and stores the data appropriately so that computations are not repeated, should more than one action be performed.

What you want is some persistence across stream batches.

There are several ways to do that:

- [`streamingContext.remember`(Minutes(5))](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations) holds on to data from previous batches for `Minutes(5)` amount of time
- [`window`ing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations) move a fixed time window across the data, allowing you to perform operations on more than one batch of data
- [`updateStateByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#updatestatebykey-operation) & [`mapWithState`](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html) provide mechanisms to maintain and transform state across batches

The approach you choose will depend largely on your use-case.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to use sparkSql for my data processing as it looks much easy for me as a beginner.  That's why I thought about Dataframe caching to persist stream batch data.I thought we can do it by caching df,inside a foreach rdd function so it will cache every previous streams

Comment: It would be nice if it worked like that. Apache Flink might be worth investigating, though I haven't used it myself.